# Flutter firebase: Update field document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible for a user to update a field in a subcollection using `collectionGroup`?

If yes, how do you do that?

If no, any advice on how to go about a problem where user A creates a field named '`posts`' and user B accesses that post and sends a `request`. After that the user has access to all the requests he/she has made using collectionGroup. Now the user wants to edit one of the list of the requests, say to cancel the request. How do I write that function?

code:

```
String adsStatus = widget.selectedRide?['Status'] ?? ''; //With this I get the status of the post.
TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final id = widget.selectedRide.id; //This is the DocId. How I use it to edit the status? Say the status should be something like this "Status" : "Canceled"
                print(id);
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Cancel Ride',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
              ))
```

Comment: to edit or delete a collection u need to have DocId i mean, the request have a Id which is generated by Firebase manually or u set that. When u have that id, u can edit or delete

Comment: Thank you. I have accessed the DocId as  edited above. Could u help me use it write the code for editing? BTW: The access is directly from collectionGroup(Requests)